# Unable to create PostGIS extension

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-extensions

I am working on a CentOS 7 server with PostGIS 3.2 installed.
When I try to create the PostGIS extension using `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/pgsql-15/lib/postgis-3.so": libgeos_c.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Note that `/usr/pgsql-15/lib/postgis-3.so` exists.

Both paths that lead to `postgis-3.so` AND `libgeos_c.so.1` are in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Here's the output of `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
/usr/pgsql-15/lib:/usr/local/lib:
```

`ldd /usr/pgsql-15/lib/postgis-3.so` gives:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc309dd000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002b0c9c9b5000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00002b0c9ccb7000)
libgeos_c.so.1 => /usr/local/lib/libgeos_c.so.1 (0x00002b0c9cfbf000)
libproj.so.12 => /usr/local/lib/libproj.so.12 (0x00002b0c9d1f1000)
libxml2.so.2 => /lib64/libxml2.so.2 (0x00002b0c9d45a000)
libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00002b0c9d7c4000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00002b0c9d9da000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00002b0c9dbde000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002b0c9ddf4000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002b0c9c471000)
libgeos-3.6.2.so => /usr/local/lib/libgeos-3.6.2.so (0x00002b0c9e1c2000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002b0c9e570000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib64/liblzma.so.5 (0x00002b0c9e78c000)
```

My PostgreSQL server is started by systemd using

```bash
systemctl start postgresql-15
```

If I look for the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the output of `cat /proc/12345/environ | xargs -0 -n 1 echo` (where 12345 is the process ID of the postmaster process), it is not there.

How can I create the PostGIS extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable in the environment of the PostgreSQL database server. Since you start PostgreSQL via systemd, you have to edit the service file:

```bash
sudo systemctl edit postgresql-15
```

That launches an editor, into which you write:

```
[Service]
Environment='LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/pgsql-15/lib:/usr/local/lib'
```

Restart PostgreSQL, and the server should have the variable set in its environment.